# Editing CSS through JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change an element's style through javascript, but my code doesn't seem to be working. Any help?

```js
document.getElementById("box").style.background = #00ff00;
```

```css
#box {
  background: #ff00ff;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div id="box"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `backgroundColor` not `background` (in JavaScript).

Comment: Put quotes around `#00ff00`. So you'll get `'#00ff00`. Open your console (hit F12) and you'll see these errors immediately.

Comment: For width, you need to specify units (again, as strings). Ex: `'10px'`, `'10%'`, `'10em'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need quotes around the color.

`document.getElementById("box").style.background = "#00ff00";`

You can see it working here:  https://jsfiddle.net/royq5og0/

Also, if you open the developer tools in your browser (F12) it will show you the error with your original code.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You're just missing quotation marks around the color:

```js
document.getElementById("box").style.background = "#00ff00";
```

```css
#box {
  background: #ff00ff;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code can be used to change the width in javascript

```
document.getElementById('box').style.width = '10px';
```

or you can apply using [setAttribute](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp),using this method u can apply multiple styles at a time,like width,height etc.

```
document.getElementById('box').setAttribute("style", "width: 10px");
```

or you can use [cssText](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_csstext.asp) as well,to apply multiple styles in a single statement

```
document.getElementById("box").style.cssText = "width:10px;height:10px"
```

Answer (score 0):

Add quotes when using any colour codes such as RGB, Hex etc.

```
document.getElementById("box").style.background = '#00ff00';
```

or using JQuery you can do:

```
$("#box").css("background-color","#00ff00");
```

This is a useful link for changing CSS stuff via JQuery which is nice and convenient as selection is much easier: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_css.asp

Hope this all helps.